# Convert object to int in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, integer, valueerror

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
RangeIndex: 144 entries, 0 to 143
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Manager ID      144 non-null object
Defect Count    144 non-null object
Transactions    144 non-null object
DPMO            144 non-null object
```

I want to  convert Defect Count, Transaction and DPMO to integer to do some calculation. I used astype to convert it to integer but it throws me an valueError. The one i tried is for only 'Defect Count'. How can i convert all 3 at once. I also tried to_numeric but converts most of my data to 'NAN'. That '2,721' on valueError is one of the data on defect count.

```
Managers_DPMO['Defect Count'] = Managers_DPMO['Defect Count'].astype(str).astype(int)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,721'
```

Comment: You need to remove the comma or other nonnumeric characters in your data, pandas doesn't know how to parse them as numbers

Comment: What do/don’t you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 0):

You have got at least one value with a comma thousand separator.
Try reading your file as:

```
df.read_csv('filename.csv', thousands=',')
```

Another option can be:

```
Managers_DPMO['Defect Count']=pd.to_numeric(Managers_DPMO['Defect Count'], downcast='integer')
```

Comment: Yes, there are some values with commas. I have created df using append method.    Managers_DPMO = Managers_DPMO.append(pd.Series(values,index= columns),ignore_index = True). I believe append does not have thousands argument

Comment: Was going to update my answer to reflect your comment, but I see @Celius-Stingher beat me to it.

Comment: @Learner Can you share more of your program? Keep in mind that repeatedly appending to a DataFrame tends to kill performance.

Comment: I have used a for loop to get all the values that i want from a website.  Is there any alternative besides append for what i am trying to achieve. The solution mentioned by @Celius-Stingher worked for single column but did not work for multiple columns.  for i in range(0,len(rows)):
    tds = rows[i].find_all('td')
    if len(tds) == 4:
        values = [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text]
    else:
        values = [td.text for td in tds]
  Managers_DPMO = Managers_DPMO.append(pd.Series(values,index= columns),ignore_index = True)

Comment: Change of approach: if you know which columns should hold `int` data then apply the conversion before adding to the dataframe e.g. int(tds[1].text)

Comment: Updated answer with another option. Btw, you only have 4 column in your dataframe so there is nothing stopping you from applying the same solution to other columns directly (this is a reply to your "but did not work for multiple columns").

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 0buz answer, you can try replacing the stripping the problematic characters and then converting it to int:

```
Managers_DPMO['Defect Count'] = Managers_DPMO['Defect Count'].str.strip(',.').astype(int)
```